# reversing an array of strings in c

Tags: c, c-strings

So I'm trying to reverse an array of strings. The code is working but the issues are:

1. After the last input I have to enter an extra char (any char will do) and press enter in order for the code to execute.
2. That it prints 2 random char or `??` before the output.
   Can anyone please explain why it's printing those `??`...

code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int     main(void)
{
    int     tot_books;
    int     i;
    int     j;

    scanf("%d\n", &tot_books);

    char    titles[tot_books][101];

    i = 0;
    while (i < tot_books)
    {
        scanf("%[^\n]\n", titles[i]);
        i++;
    }

    while (tot_books >= 0)
    {
        printf("%s\n", titles[tot_books]);
        tot_books--;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

output:

```
7
Germinal
Le petit prince
Le meilleur des mondes
L'ecume des jours
L'Odyssee
Les miserables
Crime et Chatiment
d
��
Crime et Chatiment
Les miserables
L'Odyssee
L'ecume des jours
Le meilleur des mondes
Le petit prince
Germinal
```

Comment: `printf("%s\n", titles[tot_books]);` arrays are numbered from zero, valid indexes are `0 .. (tot_books-1)`. The first iteration of the printing loop reaches one beyond the array.

Comment: So you need to decrement `tot_book` before the loop that prints.

Comment: Replace `scanf("%[^\n]\n", titles[i]);` with `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", titles[i]);` to  improve the experience at the end of input, but make sure you check the return value.  (`fgets` would be even better, though)

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are indexed from `zero` to `length - 1`

do you need to:

```
    while (tot_books > 0)
    {
        printf("%s\n", titles[tot_books - 1]);
        tot_books--;
    }
```

The first problem is explained in the duplicate link.

Comment: Awesome ^^ Thanks :)